# Referencing a Linked Server in a Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a SQL Server with a Linked Server object to another SQL Server.  The linked SQL Server has a Linked Server object which is using another OLE provider.  Let's call them LSA and LSB.  Queries against LSB look like this:

```
[LSB]...[Table]
```

I can successfully query this by using openquery from the main server like this:

```
select * from openquery(LSA, 'select * from [LSB]...[Table]')
```

However, openquery has some limitations, so I want to know how to reference LSB directly when querying from the main server through LSA.  Some things I've tried:

```
select * from [LSA].[LSB]...[Table] --Too many prefixes
select * from [LSA].[LSB...Table] --Invalid object name 'LSA.LSB...Table'
select * from [LSA].[[LSB]...[Table]] --Unclosed Quotation mark after the character string 'Table]'
```

Comment: Did you try to create a synonym to LSB object on LSA server? Is it an option for you?

Comment: You can't. An object name can have only 4 parts to it - server.database.schema.object. A synonym might work but this has all sorts of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) smell.

Comment: @SMor It is an XY Problem in a sense, but the X is out of my control so now I need to deal with the Y.  Creating a synonym seems promising though.